# C# Regex to match words from list

Tags: c#, regex

I have a following problem with my regular expression, I would like it to match *caterpillar* in the string *"This is a caterpillar s tooth"* but it matches *cat*. How can I change it?

```
        List<string> women = new List<string>()
        {
            "cat","caterpillar","tooth"
        };

        Regex rgx = new Regex(string.Join("|",women.ToArray()));


        MatchCollection mCol = rgx.Matches("This is a caterpillar s tooth");
        foreach (Match m in mCol)
        {
            //Displays 'cat' and 'tooth' - instead of 'caterpillar' and 'tooth'
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need a regex of the form `\b(abc|def)\b`.
`\b` is a word separator.

Also, you need to call `Regex.Escape` on each word.

For example:

```
new Regex(@"\b(" + string.Join("|", women.Select(Regex.Escape).ToArray()) + @"\b)");
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need `Regex.Escape` it works just wits `\b`s ?

Comment: @user: What if your one of your string contains a `\`?

Comment: should it be `\b(abc|def)\b` or `\b(abc|def\b)` - your C# examples gives a different result then your example in the first line.